# Jquery Select Just Select Elements and not its Options

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get just the select element and not its options. When I use
$('select') it brings back the select and all of its options.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the "Select minus the options" ?

Comment: Not quite sure why you want that... Maybe take a step back and tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You could delete the innerHTML in select

Comment: I am trying to loop through each select element and change its height/width 

$(elements).each(function(i, x) {     

em.css({
'width' : 250,
'height': 25
});
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (To loop through each select element and change its height/width as you mentioned in your comment)

```
$('select').each(function(i){
    $(this).width(250);
    $(this).height(25);
});​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pDacN/5/).

Answer (score 1):

dont over extend when u dont need to

```
$('select').css({ height: "25px", width: "250px" });
```

will work perfect if you dont want to just simply css:

```
select { height: 25px; width: 250px; }
```